# jquery class selector an input of a div

Tags: jquery, class, html, input, selector

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
<div class="monkey"><input class="toots"></div>
```

My attempt at selector looks like this:

```
if ($("div.monkey>'input[class=toots]'")) 
{ //something }
```

This is wrong...How is it supposed to look?

Note that the div may or may not exist so it is a condition I am seeking out in my form.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to work with the div, or the input?

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect your JS code, but you should close the `input` tag: `<input class="toots" />`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the single quotes and treat 'toots" as a class instead of a property: `$("div.monkey > input.toots")`

Answer (score 1):

if your div may or may not exist then only search the input within your html dom by using

```
if ($(":input[class=toots]")) 
{ 
     //something 
}
```

here `:input` will select all input element with attribute class with value toots.